# AWD.... Do you have to replace all 4 tires

Tags: tires, car

Please don't bash for a question like this but I've heard some things about AWD vehicles that were not so pleasing.
When one owns an AWD and has a blowout. It is best to replace all four tires because it could damage the system by having 3 worn out tires and one brand new tire? I'm not sure if I would only replace one tire but this is hypothetically speaking. 
This didn't make sense to me but being new to AWD I'd figured I would ask. Maybe if it was a completely different size wheel and tire. 
Just wondering...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. What kind of vehicle are we talking about? The reason I ask is, some AWD vehicles are more tolerant than others. Subarus are very much NOT tolerant of mixed tread depth. They can stand a couple 32'ds difference, but beyond that, it's a huge difference. I wouldn't run on new and three worn out tires on any AWD system, though. Just sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Some awd volvo models insisted on changing all 4 at the same time - it depended on the type of differential (Haldex comes to mind...) fitted between front and rear and it was very fragile to the forces that builds up... The drivetrain on old Landrovers was strong enough that the tyres would just scrub the tyres and bounce a bit...